# TreeView Winforms if a node can bee seen?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a treeView , and i want to know if some node can be seen by a user.
I mean that no node abave it not needed to be expanded that that node will be seen .

Any idea how i can check this with out rotating to upper lever for that ? 
Checked msdn but couldn't see property responsible for that ....

Some Example will really help....

Thanks a lot for help.

Comment: Do keep in mind that you can "force" a TreeNode to be visible by calling the 'EnsureVisible() method on it: that will also force a scroll if the node is scrolled outside the client area of the TreeView control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume if you want to know if a treenodes parent is expanded

TreeNode.Parent.IsExpanded

Comment: And i need to rotate till level zero . Is that the only way ?

Comment: If you know the node you want to check, then this will tell you if its parent is expanded.  You should not have to go to level 0 to do that.

Comment: Yes you are right , but still i need to check level zero because there the parent will not be expanded .

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you need:

```
Node myNode;
if(myNode.Parent.Expanded)
  //Visible
```